# Describing chages in facial expressions

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> John wails. Mike controls John. John sobs softly. Suddenly, John's face turns into angry.

What I'm trying to describe is the facial expression changes. John was sad and crying, and suddenly he get anger. Instead of saying "He get anger," I'm describing how his face changes. Is this correct in English? Is it commonly used by native English speaker?

In my language we have this kind of sentence, like describing how your face changes with different moods like laugh, crying, anger, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English has several words that are used to describe facial expressions associated with certain emotion(s).

For example, you could say he *beamed* in joy, he *scowled* in disgust, he *grimaced* in pain, he *sneered* in contempt, and he ***glowered*** in anger.

From [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/glower?q=glower):

> **glower** (*v*.) have an angry or sullen look on one’s face; scowl : *she glowered at him suspiciously*

If you aren't aware of the right word to use, though, you can also say something like:

> John's face contorted with rage.

(*contorted* could be used with other negative emotions, too, such as *sorrow* or *despair*)

There's also the idiom [*look daggers*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/look-daggers#look-daggers_1), as in:

> John *looked daggers* at Mike.

which means John glared at him with a personal, angry, spiteful look.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks a lot. These are words I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should say "John got/became/turned angry." or "John's face turned red."

You can say "John got upset when something happened."

And just as a FYI, you should say "he gets/got angry" **rather than** "he get anger."

Comment: Okay, Is the following kind of sentence valid in English? "his fear turns into a smile".

Comment: @T2E You can say that; but it is more effective to juse two parallel terms, either "his fear turns into joy" or "his grimace turns into a smile".